# Whats the Simplest way to pass multiple model to asp mvc View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use a single View file to render all my reports which has Clients Model, Fees Model, Suit Model and other models.

Comment: is not possible to get all models in single view. you can use render action to get all index in single view page

Comment: Create a view model containing properties for each of the models you want.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean @SaravananArunagiri

Comment: create List View for each model, then call all view using render action from main view @VictorC

Comment: if beginner refer this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/multiple-models-in-single-view-in-mvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only one model can be passed from view. If you want to pass multiple models(or rather objects) you have a few optoins

- Pass on the main model using controller and pass remaining objects as by viewbag like
  Viewbag.feesModel = something 
  Viewbag.suitModel = something 
  return View(studentModel)
- Second options to render individual actions using Html.Action